# Facebook shows wrong timezone for events when not logged in

Tags: facebook, facebook-events

I don't have a Facebook account but sometimes I end up on Facebook when searching for events such a concerts and exhibitions.

Lately Facebook has started showing the wrong time zone when you are not logged in.

For example, this [event](https://www.facebook.com/events/2471175479638984) shows *Friday, June 25, 2021 at 11.00 UNK-14.00 UNK*.

I guess that UNK means unknown?

Is the a bug in Facebook or are the trying to annoy people who are not logged in, hoping to make them create an account?